# How to looping a column value rows to get equal value on each row (Detail Table) then update status column in its Header Table (VBNET))

Tags: vb.net

> I have 2 table in SQL Server: Detail_PO and Header_PO. Let say, i
>   created a PO with id_po: PO001 and in the detail table have multi
>   item. In header i put status (Open/Closed) column and in the detail i
>   put status (0/1) column. I can solve this if the data contain 1 item
>   in detail.

```
Header table: 
id_PO | status
--------------- 
PO001   Open

Detail Table 
id_PO | id_product | qty_PO | qty_leftOver | status
--------------------------------------------------- 
PO001     DK0023     100        80             1 
PO001     YR0089     300        0              0 
PO001     RW0093     50         10             1
```

> Im stuck here in 3 days. My problem is, i want to update the Header
>   status to "Closed" if all detail status reach "0" by an button action
>   click. But if still there is detail status "1", header status still
>   Open. I thought it would be looping but i dont know which looping
>   method to used. Im sorry, im new in vbnet subject. I do really
>   appreciate if there is a help. Thanks in advance

```
Dim statusHeaderPesan As String = "Open"
Dim statusHeaderPesanClosed As String = "Closed"
Dim statusDetailPesan As Integer

query = "SELECT status FROM Detail_PO WHERE id_PO = @kode"
cmd = New SqlCommand(query, conn)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@kode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lblKodePO.Text
statusDetailPesan = cmd.ExecuteScalar

While statusDetailPesan = 0
 query = "UPDATE Header_PO SET status = @cekStatus WHERE id_PO = @kodePesan"
 cmd = New SqlCommand(query, conn)
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@cekStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 
 statusHeaderPesanClosed
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@kodePesan", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lblKodePO.Text
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End While
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your query to count the number of status that are `1`, as follows.

```
query = "SELECT Count(status) FROM Detail_PO WHERE id_PO = @kode And status = 1"
cmd = New SqlCommand(query, conn)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@kode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lblKodePO.Text
statusDetailPesan = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
```

Then, if the count is `0`, you run the update statement.

```
If statusDetailPesan = 0 Then
    query = "UPDATE Header_PO SET status = @cekStatus WHERE id_PO = @kodePesan"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(query, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@cekStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = statusHeaderPesanClosed
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@kodePesan", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lblKodePO.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()  
End If
```

Comment: It works sir, thank you very much. You save my life.